# Oxford Dictionary API not fetching data after the API migration

Tags: java, android, json

I have used Oxford Dictionary API 4 months ago, and it was working absolutely fine. But now when I try to fetch data from the API it shows error.

```
      "Authentication parameters missing"
```

I have already  changed the url requests as per the migrated v2 API.

//Here's my logcat

> "2019-07-24 20:30:41.190 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default 2019-07-24 20:30:45.612
>   21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/lemmas/en/laying
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.614 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.621 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.622 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.624 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.thereadingapp.Dictionary.Lemmas.doInBackground(Lemmas.java:41)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.624 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.thereadingapp.Dictionary.Lemmas.doInBackground(Lemmas.java:18)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.625 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.625 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 2019-07-24
>   20:30:45.625 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.625 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.625 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   2019-07-24 20:30:45.627 21615-21733/com.example.thereadingapp
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)"

//code to call the lemmas

```
private void callDictionary(View view){
    Lemmas lemmas = new Lemmas(view);
    lemmas.execute(LemmasURL(word));
}

private String LemmasURL(String string){
    final String language = "en";
    final String word = string;
    final String word_id = word.toLowerCase(); 
    return "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/lemmas/" + language + "/" + word_id;
}
```

// code in asyncTask

protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id",APP_ID);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key",APP_KEY);


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
}




@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    try {

    //this code is not working


        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray result = js.getJSONArray("results");


         JSONObject lentries = result.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray larray = lentries.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");




        JSONObject inflexion = larray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray inflectionJSONArray = inflexion.getJSONArray("inflectionOf");

        String theWord = inflectionJSONArray.getString(0);
       //callDefinitionDictionary(getWord(theWord));



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, " Lemmas Feature not working");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Did you pay for accessing the Oxford Dictionaries API?

Answer (score -1):

If you are gettin:

> "Authentication parameters missing"

making a request to: https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/lemmas/en/laying

Check the values of your API Key are correct:

```
   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id",APP_ID);
  urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key",APP_KEY);
```

because probably your API Key is incorrect or **not enabled**, remember that now you have to add your credit card info [to enable de API KEY](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/admin/account/stripe?details_expected).

Comment: I have signed in for a free account. Is this is the reason behind this error

Comment: yes, now you need to set up the credit card info, to enable the api key.